# div inside col takes the full width (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8">
      <div style="background-color: #1b6d85">test</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The div with the text "test" uses the full width inside the col. So the whole cols background is #1b6d85. But why? I didnt't declare the width of this div so ´shouldn't it be only the width of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` is a *block* element so  it will use all available width by default

Use `<span>` if you want an *inline* element where width is content related by default or set the `display:inline` on the `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

Because the `<div>` element has `display: block` by default which means its width is 100% and its height is auto (auto = the size of whatever's inside).